# Special case of Minimum spanning tree problem

Tags: graph-theory, operations-research

I have a initial node called root.
In this special case of spanning tree problem I minimize the number of the branch of the tree (not only the cost of the arc) and every branch must observe one rule: 
it is consider as feasible in the problem if the sum of distance of all nodes in the branch to root is no longer than alpha (this is a parameter) times the distance from last node to root.
Is there an algorithm for this case of spanning tree problem?

Comment: What is the "last node"? Is it the father node in the directed tree?

Comment: It is the last node of the branch of the tree. For example if the branch is composed by node 0(root) -> node 2 -> node 4.
The last node is node 4.